# 1. Set the priorities of the tasks by sql

Tags: sql

I have the following sql tables :

[image]

Now I want to set the priorities of the tasks by priority3 which are assigned to more than five developers. Here Priority3 is priority name.

### Solutions I have tried  :

```
Update Priority
Set Priority_Name = priority3
From Task_Priority, Task_Assignment
Where Task_Priority. Priority_ID = Priority. Priority_ID
and  Task_Priority. Task_ID = Task_Assignment. Task_ID 
and  (select count(*) from Task_Assignment where  Task_Assignment. Task_ID= Task_Priority. Task_ID) >=5
```

2. Select the Task names which are neither assigned by any creator nor solved by any developer

### Solutions I have tried :

```
Select Tasks. Task _name 
From Tasks , Task_Assignment
Where Tasks. Task _ID = Task_Assignment. Task_ID 
And (select count(Creator_ID) from Task_Assignment
 where  Task_Assignment. Task_ID= Tasks. Task _ID)=0 
And (select count(Developer_ID) from Task_Assignment 
where  Task_Assignment. Task_ID= Tasks. Task _ID)=0
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: It would be great, if you: **(1)** provide the sample data and **(2)** sample output **(3)** the queries you have tried.

Comment: I have edited my questions .